# Windows Phone Test Framework by Expensify & CI

Tags: windows-phone-7, hudson, specflow, wp7test

How to add the Windows Phone Test Framework by Expensify testing onto Hudson?
i'm try to add a windows batch command, but it cannot be trigger successfully. 
At the same time,using the same command in cmd.exe which manually opened, the testing success.

Error log:

```
Given my app is clean installed and running
->creating datastore
->getting platform
->1 platform(s) found
->platform 'Windows Phone 7' found
->looking for device 'Windows Phone Emulator'
->2 devices found
->connecting to device...
->device Connected...
->building host...
->opening host...
->error: Failed to start ApplicationAutomationController
```

the windows batch command is ： “C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe RunSpec.js”，
the RunSpec.js come from the Example，

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it might be down to the settings in the user account for the build agent.

Is the path and environment for the Hudson user the same as for the logged in user? Does the Hudson user have permission to open and listen to the default network port used by the test framework?